# I want to be able to convert numbers into text according to the ASCII decimal table

Tags: java, string, parseint

I am trying to make it so that I can take individual three-character substrings and convert them to integers under the conditions tht the length of the String is a multiple of three.  The integers into which the partioned substrings are converted are supposed to function as relative positions in an array that contains all the printing characters of the ASCII table.

```
 String IntMessage = result.toString();
   if 
   {
   (IntMessage.substring(0,1)=="1" && IntMessage.length()%3==0)
       for(j=0;j < IntMessage.length()-2;j += 3)
           n = Integer.parseInt(IntMessage.substring(j,j+3));
           mess += ASCII[n-32];
       return mess;
```

Under otherwise conditions, the method should take the first two characters of the String and initialize them to a variable i.  In this case, the variable mess is initialized to the character in the ASCII array with an index of i-32. Then there is a for loop that takes the remaining characters and partitions them into three-digit substrings and they are taken and changed into strings according to their corresponding positions in the ASCII array. The String variables in this array are continuously added on to the the variable mess in order to get the BigInteger to String conversion of the IntMessage String.

```
   int i = Integer.parseInt(IntMessage.substring(0,2));

   mess=ASCII[i-32];
           for(l=2; l< IntMessage.length() - 2; l+=3)
               r = Integer.parseInt(IntMessage.substring(l,l+3));
               mess+=ASCII[r-32];
   return mess;
```

For some reason the method isn't working and I was wondering whether I was doing something wrong.  I know how to take an input String and convert it into a series of numbers but I want to do the opposite also.  Is there anyway you could help?

Comment: Can you please give example input and output and what your method currently does wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish, so maybe other potential posters are similarly confused. Perhaps if you gave some examples, or could clarify the goal.

Comment: The Stirng "daa" should return 100097097 so result equals 100097097. IntMessage = "100097097". What I'm trying to do is to partition the String IntMessage into individual three-digit substrings. The String mess is an empty string that takes the three-digit substrings of IntMessage starting from 100.  The method concatenates the ASCII [(100)-32] which is ASCII [68] which is "d".  Then the variable j is incrimented by three and it goes to the next substring "097" and then the substring is converted into an integer n. So the method returns ASCII [65] which is "a" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description you can use the following methods:

```
String fromIntMessage(String msg) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int x = (msg.length() % 3 - 3) % 3; x < msg.length(); x += 3) {
        int chr = Integer.parseInt(msg.substring(Math.max(x, 0), x + 3));
        result.append(Character.toString((char) (chr - 32)));
    }
    return result.toString();
}

String toIntMessage(String string) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
        result.append(String.format("%03d", c + 32));
    }
    return result.charAt(0) == '0' ? result.substring(1) : result.toString();
}
```

which will give you

```
toIntMessage("DAA")             // => "100097097"
fromIntMessage("100097097")     // => "DAA"
```