# BigInteger to String according to ASCII

Tags: java, string, integer, ascii

Is there a way to convert a series of integers to a String according to the ASCII table.  I want to take the ASCII value of a String and convert it back to a String. For example,

```
97098097=> "aba"
```

I really need an effective way of taking an integer and converting it to a String according to its ASCII value.  This method must also take into account the fact that there is `no zero` in front of the `'9'` when the String `"aba"` has an ASCII value of `97098097` as `'a'` has an ASCII value of `097` and a String `"dee"` has one of `100101101`.  This means that not every number will have an ASCII value that has a number of digits that is a multiple of three.

If you have any misunderstandings of what I'm trying to do please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to be able to convert numbers into text according to the ASCII decimal table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585394/i-want-to-be-able-to-convert-numbers-into-text-according-to-the-ascii-decimal-tab)

Answer (score 1):

No lookup table required.

```
    while (string.length() % 3 != 0)
    {
        string = '0' + string;
    }
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i += 3)
    {
        result += (char)(Integer.parseInt(string.substring(i, i + 3)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would create some sort of lookup table in your code with all the ascii values and their String equivalent. Then take the big int and convert it to a String. Then do the mod of 3 with the length of your bigint string to determine if you need to add 1, 2, or no 0's to the front of it. Then just grab every 3 integers from the front of the number, compare it to the lookup table, and append the corresponding value to your result string.

Example:

Given `97098097`
You would convert it to: `"97098097"`

Then you do a mod with 3 resulting in a value of 1, so 1 zero needs to be added.

Append 1 zero: `"097098097"`

Then grab every 3 from the front and compare to look up table:

`097 -> a`, so `result += "a"`

`098 -> b`, so `result += "b"`

`097 -> a`, so `result += "a"`

You end with result being "aba"